Convexity of domain of unconditional convergence for power series in Banach algebras
Let $X$ be a Banach algebra. Consider the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$. Let $D$ denote the set of elements in $X$ where this power series converges unconditionally (not merely the convergence of the partial sum). To exclude trivial cases, we assume that $D$ contains elements other than $0$.
In the case $X = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, it is known that there exists some $r > 0$ such that $D = B_r(0)$ or $D = \overline{B_r(0)}$, where $B_r(0)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$, and $\overline{B_r(0)}$ is its closure. This MSE question provides an example where $D$ is a closed ball.
My Question:
In the general case of a Banach algebra, I could not find a description of the shape of $D$. The results from this MSE question show that we cannot expect $D$ to always be precisely a ball. However, is it possible to prove that $D$ cannot have an excessively "strange" shape? Specifically, I would like to know if $D$ must be a convex set.
I think this is a reasonable conjecture, but I do not know how to prove it, and perhaps the proof is very simple. I am also unfamiliar with relevant counterexamples, so I do not know whether any simple counterexamples exist. I am aware of the Orlicz–Pettis theorem concerning series in Banach spaces, but I do not know if it applies to this problem of power series in Banach algebras.
Besides convexity, I have a few other questions about the shape of $D$. While these are not the focus of this post, I believe they are worth mentioning for completeness. These questions also seem quite natural. For example:

Must $D$ be an open or closed set?
Does there exist an open set $U$ such that $U \subseteq D \subseteq \overline{U}$?

If necessary, I will consider asking these additional questions in a separate post.

No, $D$ is not necessarily convex. For example, let the power series be given by,
$$p(x) = \sum_{k \geq 2, k \text{ even}} x^k = x^2 + x^4 + \cdots$$
Let $X = M_2(\mathbb{C})$ equipped with the spectral norm (or, really, any norm that makes it into a Banach algebra would work). Note that since $e_{12}^2 = e_{21}^2 = 0$, we have $2e_{12}, 2e_{21} \in D$. However, let $T = e_{12} + e_{21} = \frac{1}{2}(2e_{12} + 2e_{21})$, then, again as $e_{12}^2 = e_{21}^2 = 0$, we may easily calculate, for any $k \geq 2$, $k$ even,
$$T^k = (e_{12} + e_{21})^k = e_{12}e_{21}e_{12}\cdots e_{21} + e_{21}e_{12}e_{21}\cdots e_{12} = I$$
So,
$$p(T) = \sum_{k \geq 2, k \text{ even}} T^k = I + I + \cdots$$
diverges, and $T \notin D$.

Let me also answer the two additional questions you have. The answers to both are no. For example, let,
$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k!)^2x^k$$
and let $X = B(\ell^2)$ equipped with the operator norm. Let $T \in B(\ell^2)$ be defined by,
$$Te_n = \frac{1}{n}e_{n+1}$$
and let $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\text{span}\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$. Then $P_nT$ is nilpotent for all $n$, so $p(P_nT)$ converges unconditionally, and thus $P_nT \in D$, for all $n$. Note that $P_nT \to T$, but,
$$\begin{split}
p(T)e_1 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k!)^2T^ke_1\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k!)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{k!}e_{k+1}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k!)e_{k+1}
\end{split}$$
which diverges, so $p(T)$ diverges and $T \notin D$. This shows $D$ is not closed. It is not open either, as $0 \in D$ but $\alpha I \notin D$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Finally, for the third question, let,
$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k!)x^k$$
and let $X = M_2(\mathbb{C})$ equipped with the spectral norm. Note that all nilpotent matrices are in $D$. Conversely, if $p(T)$ converges unconditionally, then,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k!)\|T^k\| < \infty \Rightarrow \lim_k \|T^k\|^{1/k} = 0$$
So by spectral radius formula, $\sigma(T) = \{0\}$ and thus $T$ is nilpotent, as it is a finite-dimensional matrix. Thus, $D$ is exactly the set of $2$-by-$2$ nilpotent matrices. But this means $D$ has no interior, as $T + \alpha I$ is not nilpotent for any nilpotent $T$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Hence, no open $U$ as in your third question can exist.
